# Scatter mapping (scatterm) in MATLAB - MarkerEdgeColor for NaN

Tags: matlab, scatter

I am plotting some points on a map. I want the markers to have an edge color. However, NaN points that would normally not show up as a color are showing up when I specify a marker edge color. How can I make the marker edge color be 'none' for those sites?

Current code:

```
scatterm(obs_lat(id),wrapTo360(obs_lon(id)),120,cell2mat(avg_mod_obstop10{y}{1}(id)),'filled','d','MarkerEdgeColor',[0.5 .5 .5])
```

Comment: is it `scatterm` a misspelling for `scatter`? If yes, I cannot reproduce the behavior. `scatter(1:11,[NaN 1:10],120,1:11,'filled','d','MarkerEdgeColor',[0.5 .5 .5])` does not show a marker at 1.

Comment: `scatterm` is just used for mapping. I see that it `scatter` doesn't seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find where the values are NaN and do not plot them.

```
id1 = find(~isnan(cell2mat(avg_obs_data_top10{y}(id))) ==1);

scatterm(obs_lat(id(id1)),wrapTo360(obs_lon(id(id1))),150,cell2mat(avg_obs_data_top10{y}(id(id1))),'filled','p','MarkerEdgeColor',[0.5 .5 .5])
```